# After updating to the most recent OS, I can no longer restore ipsw

Tags: restore, jailbreak, ipsw

Yesterday I used Shift click on "Check for update" and selected an IPSW (version 12.4, which is still signed) and the update put my iPhone into recovery mode but failed to install. Later I tried shift click again on the same iPhone and on an iPod Touch and I got the error: "You are already on the most recent iOS" (even though earlier the update couldn't install).

Today I tried using Shift click again and I was able to select the IPSW again.

Does anyone know why this would happen - i.e. why the IPSW was available, and then it wasn't, and now it is again?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you updated a jailbroken phone it is no longer jailbroken & you'll have to wait for the new jailbreak.

Comment: @Tetsujin I pressed Shift click on "check for update" early yesterday, selected an ipsw (12.4) which is still signed and the update put my iphone into recovery mode and failed to install. Later I tried shift click again on the same and on an ipod touch and I got the error: "You are already on the most recent ios". Today I shift click and I can select the ipsw again. Was wondering why.